# SQL: Error showing incorrect number of rows

Tags: sql

I would like to show the average production cost of games that were produced between 2010 and 2015 and were rated higher than 7.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT avg(production_cost)
FROM games
GROUP BY games.production_year, games.rating
HAVING games.production_year between 2010 AND 2015 AND games.rating > 7;
```

Can someone take a look?

Comment: Hint:  You don't need `GROIUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it with just a where comment. I thought if I used an aggregate function I had to use     GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work well

```
SELECT ISNULL(avg(production_cost), 0)
FROM games
WHERE games.production_year between 2010 AND 2015 AND games.rating > 7;
```

[Run in SqlFillde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59e73/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the query again without group by.
Having takes care of ur time duration. Remove below line. `GROUP BY games.production_year, games.rating.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT games.production_year, games.rating,avg(production_cost)
FROM games
WHERE games.production_year between 2010 AND 2015 AND games.rating > 7
GROUP BY games.production_year, games.rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT avg(production_cost) FROM games where games.production_year between 2010 AND 2015 AND games.rating > 7